# Failed to Open Stream using laravel install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying out Laravel and after installation I get the following when attempting to start a new application:

using code: `laravel new blog`

I get:

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/laravel_d4381b5ce250405766ef8b9fa784b256.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/ren/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 81
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /home/ren/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 99
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/ren/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer/src/NewCommand.php on line 101
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

Comment: Does your user have permission to write to /var/www/html?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems the user you're running the command with, doesn't have the necessary permissions to write to `/var/www/html/`. Try changing the permissions or owner of that directory. Try:

```
sudo chown $USER /var/www/html
```

The `$USER` variable contains the logged in username (in your case `ren`), so it will make your user the owner of that directory. Then run the installation command:

```
laravel new blog
```

Answer (score -1):

As a noob, it took me a few good painstakingly hours to figure this out. As far as my understanding goes, you'll need to initiate the new project with `laravel new <project>` in a 777 directory. So you'd go like:

```
 ### make directory and grant full permissions
 sudo mkdir /var/www/laravel
 sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/
 cd /var/www/laravel/

 ### run laravel installer
 laravel new web-project

 ### move your project in www root
 sudo mv web-project /var/www/
```

The last bit where you move the directory is optional and you may leave it there or move it to anywhere your **vhost** might be set up.

*Personal note*: I was actually hoping setting up a new Laravel app to be easier than this. I'm confident however it will get easier with practice :)